# PostBuildEvent in WindowsInstaller project returns error code '1'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, post-build-event

I have a Windows Installer (VS 2008) project and I want to create a very simple post build event, which just opens the target folder, with the installer selected.

So I've typed the following in the PostBuildEvent field:

> explorer.exe /select, $(BuiltOuputPath)

The problem is I get the following error:

> ERROR: Error de 'PostBuildEvent' con el código de error '1' 'Error no
>   especificado'

Which translates as something like:

> ERROR: 'PostBuildEvent' error with error code '1' 'Unspecified error'

The thing is, the folder opens, with the installer selected and all, but it keeps giving me error.

So, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: does it happens only from a post build event? What about if you run the command line yourself?

Comment: If I run the command line myself, I get the same error. So if I do `explorer.exe /select, (path)` then `echo %errorlevel%` I get '1'. But I've just found that if I do `start explorer.exe /select, (path)`it works fine (from the command line, I'll try the PostBuildEvent later)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine with "start":

> start explorer.exe /select, $(BuiltOuputPath)

Answer (score 1):

Simply change `"BuiltOuputPath"` to the exact path of your setup project output for example:

> **"$(E:\INFO BANK\Info Bank Project\Setup2\Debug)"**

i am sure the error will disappear .. good luck